# Getting working hyperlinks in the feature attributes of a WMS in Qgis

Tags: qgis, wms, fields-attributes, hyperlink, identify

I have a Geoserver WMS of point locations with urls in one of its attribute fields. If I do a getFeatureInfo request on this in Qgis, using identify, it just returns a string without hyperlink functionality on the urls. For my application it should be able to link to external websites and open local file folders. Preferably without having to copy and paste.
So far, I tried to convert this string to a html link by wrapping it in html-tags, like:

```
<a href="url" target="_blank">open</a>
```

As shown in the image the hyperlink tries to open in another instance of QGIS instead of a browser, which fails.

[image]

**My Question**

Is there any way to disclose urls in the feature attributes of a WMS **in Qgis** with working hyperlinks?

Comment: Have you tried to use &info_format=text/html?

Comment: I tried, there is no difference. Also, I think the 'HTML' in the box above the output already specifies the format of the request.

Comment: Info_format is not selected automatically even QGIS does use some default and yes, it seems to be already "html" in your selection box.  Test how it works by using this link as it is and by editing the info_format into text/html http://demo.geo-solutions.it/geoserver/topp/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&QUERY_LAYERS=topp%3Astates_test&STYLES&LAYERS=topp%3Astates_test&INFO_FORMAT=text%2Fplain&FEATURE_COUNT=50&X=50&Y=50&SRS=EPSG%3A4326&WIDTH=101&HEIGHT=101&BBOX=-103.22%2C36.518%2C-94.350%2C45.395

Comment: Actually you wrote that the link works but it is not opened in browser. I do not know why, sorry. I have been using the same system with other clients with success.

Comment: Thanks anyway. The links do work when I use them in a browser, so I think the problem is with Qgis. In your system did you use Qgis as a frontend? If so which version did you use?

Comment: 1/2 I have the same problem with QGIS 2.14.17.  The following service has URLs in the GetFeatureInfo response http://ogc.bgs.ac.uk/cgi-bin/BGS_BGS-HPA_Radon_Potential/wms?service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities&  e.g. http://ogc.bgs.ac.uk/cgi-bin/BGS_BGS-HPA_Radon_Potential/wms?language=eng&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&BBOX=52.804653,-1.577809,52.959911,-1.349062&CRS=EPSG:4326&WIDTH=662&HEIGHT=450&LAYERS=GBR_BGS-HPA_625K_RADON_POTENTIAL&STYLES=&FORMAT=image/png&TRANSPARENT=true&QUERY_LAYERS=GBR_BGS-HPA_625K_RADON_POTENTIAL&INFO_FORMAT=text/html&I=194&J=162& works in a browser.

Comment: 2/2 Links to pdf don't open in QGIS, links with HTML work in the Identify results window, but if you try to `Open link in New Window` just get a blank page as illustrated above.